# wget to mirror site make exception to `--no-parent`

Tags: wget

I want to mirror a site using wget:

```
wget    --mirror                        \
        --convert-links                 \
        --adjust-extension              \
        --page-requisites               \
        --no-parent                     \
        --wait=2                        \
        --progress=bar                  \
        --show-progress                 \
        --output-file=$LOG_FILE         \
        --directory-prefix=$DIR_PATH    \
    $URL
```

Now, it has been working well but I have come accross a website where the main page from which I want to start is under `https://www.website.org/unique_path/here.html` but it contains references to files or links that are like: `https://www2.website.org/unique_path/there.pdf`. However, `--no-parent` prevents the download of the content under `www2...` URL. Is there a way to circumvent this? (Or some option that would explicitly work as `--no-parent` by specifying some wildcard expression that it is ok to go and download here and there?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to circumvent this?

You are apparently looking for [Spanning Hosts options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Spanning-Hosts.html), you must provide `-H` option and then you might deliver comma-separated list of acceptable domains via `-D`, using your example

```
wget <your current options here> -H -D www.website.org,www2.website.org <your URL here>
```